# How do I scale serrano chile?

Tags: mexican-cuisine, chili, chili-peppers, recipe-scaling

I'm following a recipe that calls for *2 chiles serranos* and *serves 6*. The dish is not hot/spicy at all, and I wouldn't want to lose this when scaling.

I need to scale by 6, and the dish should serve about 36 persons. Should I now use *12 chiles serranos*?

They will be cooked with the rest of the ingredients, adding some flavour. Unless I'm missing something about this recipe, you are not supposed to eat the chiles!

[This is the recipe](http://pastebin.com/hsVpiw6p) I'm following. It's from a Diana Kennedy book.

I don't want the dish to become super hot!!!

Answer (score 3):

I would follow the age-old cooking rule that says you can always add, but you can never take away. In other words, I'd add, say, 6 chillis, see how that tasted, and add more if you think it needs it.

Comment: This is important with chilies as they can vary considerable from batch to batch.

Comment: @dmckee: But the variance will be reduced in larger quantities. If it's been not-spicy with two chiles several times, surely that's enough data to be confident it won't when scaled up. Also, in this case, you *can't* add. The chiles are being used mostly for the flavor; they're whole so the seeds and membrane aren't exposed to the dish, and the flavor comes out as they cook for half an hour.

Comment: @Jefromi In some chilies a substantial part of the variance derives from the conditions the plant was subjected to while growing. This can result in whole crops being unusually hot or mild. This is a big deal in New Mexico, where a dry year implies scorching hot chilies. I suppose that commercially provided chilies may come from mixed crops, but I wouldn't count on it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why you think it'd get hotter if you scale the serranos the same as everything else. You certainly *could* play it safe by starting with less, but given the recipe, you wouldn't be able to add more in later. I would definitely use 12, so that you get as much of their flavor as you do in your normal-sized recipe.